# как отследить выключение компьютера

Tags: python-3.x

мне нужно сделать программу одной из функций которой будет измерение работы компьютера за день, неделю месяц и т.д, но для этого мне нужно либо отслеживать выключениe/включение компьютера либо в тупую делать проверку работы компьютера каждую минуту, можно ли как-нибудь отследить выключение компьютера или нет, если можно то как

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: в журнале событий есть записи про включение/выключение компьютера. Если получится добраться до них питоном, то остальное дело техники.